# How to make display inline-block only for the two elements inside flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make two elements as a display inline block element inside the flex container. But it is not working. Following is my html code

```
<div id="main-container">
    <div id="col1">
    first
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
    second
    </div>
    <div id="col3">
    third
    </div>
    <div id="col4">
    fourth
    </div>
</div>
```

and my css is

```
    #main-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 8px 24px;
    }

    #col1 {
    background: blue;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    min-height: inherit;

    }

    #col2 {
    background: yellow;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    min-height: inherit;
    display:inline-block;
    }

    #col3 {
    background: green;
    flex: 1;
    display:inline-block;
    min-height: inherit;
    }

    #col4 {
    background: indigo;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    min-height: inherit;

    }
```

Here I am trying to make only **col2** and **col3** as a single row. How to make it.? Like below example

```
----
First
-------------
Second | thrid
--------------
fourth
-----
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0kmuw128/19/)

Actually I am trying with mat-table and I cannot able to add any div in between two cells. For the demo purpose I made this question with a div tag.  I need to merge below red high lighted cells as a single row.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#main-container` has `flex-direction: column`  so `div's` are displayed as columns.

It is necessary to add a container and just apply `display: flex` for it. By default `display: flex` has `flex-direction: row`:

```css
#main-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 8px 24px;
}

#col1 {
    background: blue;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    min-height: inherit;

}

#col2 {
    background: yellow;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    min-height: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
}

#col3 {
    background: green;
    flex: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: inherit;
}

#col4 {
    background: indigo;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    min-height: inherit;

}

.foo {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
    <div id="col1">
      first
    </div>
    <div class="foo">
      <div >
        second
      </div>
      <div>
        third
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="col4">
      fourth
    </div>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE:**

If it is not possible to add container, then you can use `display: grid` with `grid-template-areas:`:

```css
.main-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "col_1 col_1""col_2 col_3""col_4 col_4";
}

.col-1 {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    grid-area: col_1;
}

.col-2 {
    background-color: lightpink;
    grid-area: col_2;
}

.col-3 {
    background-color: orange;
    grid-area: col_3;
}

.col-4 {
    background-color: olivedrab;
    grid-area: col_4;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="col-1">
      first
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      second
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      third
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      fourth
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Read more about grid-template-areas.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I am trying with mat-table and I cannot able to add any div in between two cells. For the demo purpose I made this question with a div tag.

Comment: @mkHun Could you create [a stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com)?

Comment: I have created the (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-pj5kqx?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)[stackblitz]

Comment: @mkHun it says error `The "mat-" prefix cannot be used in ng-material v1 compatibility mode. It was used on an "mat-table" element.`